# Swift - what should the default values of properties be in the parent class?

Tags: swift, class, oop, abstract-class

Not sure if I worded this question correctly, but here's my issue: I have a base class and a subclass, and my base class should never be instantiated on its own (in other languages it would be abstract). I know abstract classes aren't a thing in Swift. I have some computed read-only properties that change what they return in each subclass; they are more or less customized constants. Firstly, are overridden computed properties the best way to handle this kind of thing? Secondly, if these variables need to get initialized, i.e. can't be nil, what should they be initialized to in the parent class? Is there a way to otherwise indicate that the parent class shouldn't be initialized on its own?

Comment: Swift has protocols and protocol extensions instead of abstract classes. You should create a protocol instead of your class, which has all the publicly visible functions and then implement all, which is known in the base class as a protocol extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use protocol instead of base class in your case. All common implementation can be done in protocol extensions and you won't need to provide default values for constants - just specify required `get` methods in the protocol.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this, but I'm aware of Swifts protocol feature and wasn't sure it'd be right for something like this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to OOP's "is-a" principle, shouldn't parent classes always be classes and not protocols? Or is swift a bit different in that respect?

Comment: I think it is the right usecase for protocols, although I can't point to more authoritative sources :) In a way swift protocols act as an abstract class - they define interface and provide ability to implement some parts of those interfaces. But protocols also are more flexible than class inheritance - multiple inheritance is less awkward and you don't need to provide implementation in base class if it does not make sense like in your case.